# Will a 4 TB or 6 TB fit this PC?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, storage

[https://www.amazon.com/Seagate-Desktop-7200RPM-SATA-Cache/dp/B00BFFQMCY?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BFFQMCY)

the question is not solely aimed at seagate drives but any other competitor with 4-6 TB drives
I currently have an 1 TB and want a bigger one and worried about compatibility

[image: blah blah]

Comment: Any 3,5in drive should fit int any 3,5in drive bay.

Comment: @LPChip - Windows 7 64-bit supports GPT. I have personally used disks larger then 2 TB on Windows 7.

Comment: @RalfFriedl - In fact NOT true. They moved the screw-holes on drives 'bigger' than 4TB... so check for fixing compatibility. [Some drives restored the old fixings for compatibility, but not all]

Comment: @Tetsujin: Technically it'll still _fit_ perfectly fine, you'll just need to get creative about properly securing it in place.

Comment: @grawity - depends on your fixing structure. They won't go in my Mac Pros unless I buy new drive sleds with the new fixing locations, as there is no tolerance in the sled/SATA interface. I guess in a regular bent tin rattly ATX case you could just shove them roughly into place & hold them with blu tack :P

Answer (score 2):

The requirements for a harddisk this size are the following:

- Motherboard/BIOS needs to be able to support it, but usually a bios firmware update could add support at a later stage.
- It must support and use UEFI
- The filesystem needs to be able to support this. This means NTFS, XFAT on windows with GUID partition table.
- Windows 7 or newer (because of GUID GPT and UEFI requirements)
- It must use a windows 64-bit OS.

Given that you use Windows 10, you can use the GUID GPT. Your motherboard should also support the drive without the need to do a bios firmware update, so yes, you can use a disk this large.

Answer (score 2):

See the Microsoft article
[Windows support for hard disks that are larger than 2 TB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2581408/windows-support-for-hard-disks-that-are-larger-than-2-tb).

It lists the conditions for using a disk larger than 2 TB :

- The disk must be initialized as GPT
- Boot must use UEFI and not BIOS
- Windows must be 64-bit
- The disk controller must support 64-bit addresses

You should check these conditions, but I think your computer is recent
enough for them to apply.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is not solely aimed at seagate drives but any other competitor with 6 TB drives I currently have an 1 TB and want a bigger one and worried about compatibility

**Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10** all support creating a single 6 TB partition.

> Windows can only boot from GPT on UEFI-based computers running 64-bit
>   versions of Windows 10, 8, 7, Vista, and corresponding server
>   versions.

However, when Windows is installed on an unallocated disk, several partitions will be created by the installer, so the system partition will not be 6 TB but slightly smaller.  This is due to the fact several required partitions will be created.  This is the case for any version of Windows that supports GPT.

1. EFI System Partition (Required)
2. Recovery Image Partition (optional but created by default)
3. Windows System Partition (Required)
4. Microsoft Reserved Partition (Required Windows 10 only)

> Each partition can have a maximum of 18 EB (Exabytes)

[image]

> When you deploy Windows to a UEFI-based device, you must format the
>   hard drive that includes the Windows partition by using a GUID
>   partition table (GPT) file system. Additional drives may use either
>   the GPT or the master boot record (MBR) file format.

In order to deploy Windows to a UEFI-based device the following must be true.

> To meet these conditions, the following prerequisites apply:
>
> - The disk must be initialized by using GPT.
> - The system firmware must use UEFI.
> - The latest storage drivers from your storage controller manufacturer must be installed.
> - The Windows version must be one of the following (64-bit only, but including all SKU editions):
>
>   - Windows Server 2008 or newer
>   - Windows Vista or newer
>
> Note:
>
> Windows does not support starting GPT-initialized volumes by using
>   UEFI systems on 32-bit versions of Windows. Also, legacy BIOS systems
>   do not support starting GPT-partitioned volumes.

Just because GPT allows a single partition to be 18 EB, does not mean, Windows supports it.  At the end of the day you are limited by the device controller the drive is connected to.  While it's possible your controller does not support a 6 TB drive, it's unlikely, limitations like that, typically did not get introduced to the SATA controllers that typically exist on a motherboard.

While I would love to indicate, if a 6 TB drive would work with your system, you have not provided enough information to make that conclusion.  I can tell you, that the Intel chipset that the i7 6700 supports, supports 6 TB+ drives.  So unless the physical dimensions, of the drive are incompatible with your specific system, there isn't a technical issue from the hardware nor software running on your machine.

Sources:

- [UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions)
- [Windows support for hard disks that are larger than 2 TB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2581408/windows-support-for-hard-disks-that-are-larger-than-2-tb)
- [What’s the Difference Between GPT and MBR When Partitioning a Drive?](https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will; it's new enough to [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)-format and use the entire drive. The limit for the modern [GPT partition tables](https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/) is [18 million terabytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so it's AOK!